# postprocess solr's faceted search result

Tags: php, lucene, solr, faceted-search

I'm not sure how to handle the following issues. So i hope, to get here some ideas or something like that.
I'm using lucene with solr. Every document (which is indexed in lucene) has an date-field an an topic - field (with some keywords)

By using faceted search, i'm able to calculate the frequency of every keyword at an specific date.

Example 1 (pseudo code):

```
1st search where date=today:
web=>70
apple=>35
blue=>32

2nd search where date=yesterday:
web=>65
blue=>55
apple=>5
```

But now i would like to combine the results into one solr/lucene query in order to calculate which word-frequency grows very strong and witch doesn't.
An result could be:

Example 2:

```
one search merging both querys from example 1
web=>(70,65)  <- growth +7,69%
blue=>(32,55) <- growth -41,81%
apple=>(34,5) <- growth +680%
```

Is it possible (and useful) to do this consolidation (and calclulation) inside solr or is it better to start 2 solr querys (see example 1) an postprocess the results with PHP?

Than you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the facet values a priori, you could do this with facet queries, i.e. something like `facet.query=category:web AND date:[2011-06-14T00:00:00Z TO 2011-06-14T23:59:59Z]&facet.query=category:web AND date:[2011-06-13T00:00:00Z TO 2011-06-13T23:59:59Z]&...` so you would do the cartesian product of facet values * dates.

Otherwise, to do this inside Solr I think you'd have to write some custom Java faceting code. Or do it client-side, with multiple queries as you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. But that does not exactly fit my needs. Because the "term" (for example) "web" is an result of the firs query (the result of example 1) . I can consolidate the results of the querys from example 1 by using facet.date.start, facet.date.end and facet.date.gap. But how to postprocess? If this is only possible be writing own java facetting code - so postprocessing in PHP would be the better way for me. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can use facet.date.start for this, you need a cartesian product of facet queries.

Comment: following your example, i get strange results. It seams, that solr doen't recognize "facet.query" keyword. Could this be possible? On the other hand: (fq=) works fq= and facet.query is the same, right? Finally, my solr installation seams to use the AND operator between the "fq". That mens, it doesn't count the category on the first and 2nd day, it looks like, solar searches for documents, which are at the 1st and 2nd day at the same time, which results in '
numFound="0"'

Comment: @The Bndr: facet.query docs: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.query_:_Arbitrary_Query_Faceting . fq is filter query, it's nothing like a facet query, in fact it's not for faceting at all.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like, there is some "basic knowledge" missing on my side! ;-) Thank you for supporting me - greetings from Europe.